# Regular Parametrization of a Sphere

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Is there a function $f:U→ \mathbb{R^3}$, such that:
(1) U is an open connected subset of $ \mathbb{R^2} $; (2) f is $ C^r , r≥1$; (3) the Jacobian of f is of maximal rank at all points of U; (4) $f(U)=S^2$.

Comment: Nothing to do with the Hairy Ball Theorem. You can't parametrize any compact manifold without boundary by one single chart.

Comment: The best you can do is stereographic projection, sphere minus a single point

Comment: As I hoped to have cleared, i am not using charts (which i referred to as coordinate patches) but RPR.... (an example of parametric representation are the spherical coordinates: these are regular only on a pinned sphere)

Comment: No, the question is not at all clear. Are you reading a particular book that we might know? Where did you get this problem??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface this is the sort of surface I would like to study. The problem just came to me while studying differential geometry. The book I use is the Lipshutz (Shaum is the editor).

Comment: How about the following reformulation of your question: let $n=2$. Is there a  function $f:U\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$, such that (1) $U$ is an open *connected*  subset of $\mathbb R^n$; (2) $f$ is $C^r$, $r\geq 1$; (3)  the  Jacobian  of $f$ is of maximal rank at all points of $U$; (4) $f(U)=S^n$. Note that for $n=1$ the answer is "yes" (take $f(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$).

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I am asking for! Thank you, excuse me for the question being not clear!

Comment: You mean $f:U\to\mathbb R^3$, right? [This sort of thing](http://www.spinarecipe.com/userfiles/image/Cooking%20Tips/orange-peel.jpg) should work.

Comment: yes I meant R^3 thanks. What you show is not very clear. As shown in the image the map should also be bijective, so it might aswell be an homeomorphism, which is absurd as stated in some previuos comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U = [0,1]\times[0,1]$, and $\bigl(1+\frac u{10}\bigr)f(u,v)$ looks like this:

[image]

Comment: OK, it seems to work, that's very nice!! :) let's see if I got the point. I took a spherical parametrization of a piece of sphere by $( \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (sen(\phi)cos(\theta), sen(\phi)sen(\theta), cos(\phi))$, where we can consider $(\theta, \phi) \in \mathbb{R} \times (\pi/4, 3\pi/4)$. Now I turn this thing around the x axis with continuity (in exaple by turning by $\theta / 8$. Now the map is surjective (if the turning angle is choosen right) and the jacobian seems to stay maximal!

Comment: Yes, that's it.